# selecting and formating text in richtextbox control vb6

Tags: vb6, formatting, rtf

i need to bold some text as i add them to the richtextbox control, currently here is my code

**EDIT**

```
With txtDetails
        If Not IsNullOrEmpty(title) Then
        Dim intStart As Integer
        intStart = Len(.Text)
            .Text = .Text & title '& vbCrLf
            .SelStart = intStart
            .SelLength = Len(title)
            .SelBold = True
            .SelLength = 0
            .SelBold = False
            .Text = .Text & vbNewLine
        End If
        If Not IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            .Text = .Text & value & vbNewLine
        End If
        .Text = .Text & vbNewLine
    End With
```

can anyone help me with the fix

I have made changes to the code, but still get all the subsequent test i add to be bold, insted of the one am interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to append a bolded `title` if not "missing" and a non-bolded `value` if it is not "missing."

```
Option Explicit

Private Function IsNullOrEmpty(ByVal Item As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsNull(Item) Then
        IsNullOrEmpty = True
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Item) Then
        IsNullOrEmpty = True
    ElseIf VarType(Item) = vbString Then
        If Len(Item) = 0 Then
            IsNullOrEmpty = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub cmdAppend_Click()
    With rtbDisplay
        .SelStart = &H7FFFFFFF
        If Not IsNullOrEmpty(txtTitle.Text) Then
            .SelBold = True
            .SelText = txtTitle.Text
            txtTitle.Text = ""
            .SelBold = False
            .SelText = vbNewLine
        End If
        If Not IsNullOrEmpty(txtValue.Text) Then
            .SelText = txtValue.Text
            txtValue.Text = ""
            .SelText = vbNewLine
        End If
    End With
    txtTitle.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Here I'm using TextBox controls as the data source but it should give you the general idea.  It is often cheaper to use two operations than using String concatenation to add a newline.

Fetching the current .Text and measuring it with Len() is also costly if the contents are large, so just set .SelStart to the maximum value to move to the end.

Comment: appending text to the rtb control makes the text loose its format

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what "format" you are referring to.  The code above does precisely as you asked as far as I can tell.  I don't see any "loss of format."

Answer (score 2):

Setting `.Text` has some side-effects which prevent your code from doing what you want:

1. It resets `.SelStart` so you need to save the length of `.Text` first.
2. It resets all of the formatting, so the boldness gets lost.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not into vb but I created a project and tested it out.
Try this

```vb
    With txtDetails
        .SelectionStart = 0
        .SelectionLength = txtDetails.TextLength
        .SelectionFont = New Font(txtDetails.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    End With
```

Comment: i asked a vb6 question, not vb.net